# Sending a mail locally via symfony mailer with mailhog

Tags: php, symfony, email, smtp

I have installed inside my docker mailhog like so:

```
mailhog:
image: mailhog/mailhog
ports:
  - 1025:1025 # smtp server
  - 8025:8025 # web ui
```

But no matter what config I use i keep getting the following error:

> Connection could not be established with host "mailhog:1025":
> stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for
> mailhog failed: Name or service not known

My `.env` looks like this:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://mailhog:1025
```

And in my Controller I call it like so:

```
$emailObject = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('test@com', 'Questions'))
            ->to($email)
            ->subject('test')
            ->textTemplate('email/email-template.txt.twig')
            ->context([
                // Pass any other variables you need in the context here
            ]);

        try {
           $this->mailer->send($emailObject);
        } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $exception) {
            throw new \Error($exception->getMessage());
        }
```

Is there anything else I can use or am i doing it the wrong way ?

Thank you for your help

This answer does not answer my problem,
[I'm trying to send mails through mailhog using laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75893493/im-trying-to-send-mails-through-mailhog-using-laravel)
no configuration no matter what i try works